# Retrieving package install URL via sfdx

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, continuous-integration

I'm upgrading our build system to use `sfdx`, and I'm trying to automate all packaging operations for our managed package.

Once a new package version has been created via `sfdx`, I would like to retrieve the package installation URL so that I can document it somewhere. I tried using `sfdx force:package1:version:display`, but I was surprised to see that it only returns things I already know and supplied at build time (package name, version and ID). There is no sign of the package install URL.

Is there a way to programmatically retrieve the install URL from a package that I just created with sfdx?

Edit: apparently the install URL can be created like this:

`https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=<package version ID>`

Would this work?

Edit: I'm using 1st generation packaging (1GP). I'm not planning to use 2GP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the solution I used in the end. I build the install URL by concatenating a well-known string with the package ID, as follows:

`https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=<package version ID>`

This is working well so far for us, although it feels like a workaround

Answer (score 12):

You can add the --verbose flag to  sfdx force:package:version:list and it will give you the Installation URLs

```
sfdx force:package:version:list --verbose
```

Comment: How did this have zero votes before today??  This is *exactly* the programmatic (and hindsight) way to retrieve these that I was looking for.  Thank you Samir! 

Answer (score 1):

**package:version:create:report**

Retrieves details about a package version creation request in the Dev Hub org.

**sfdx force:package:version:create:list  -v DevHub1**

**sfdx force:package:version:create:report -i 08c2v000000KzJsAAK -v DevHub1**

*=== Package Version Create Request
NAME                           VALUE
─────────────────────────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
ID                             08c2v000000KzJsAAK
Status                         Success
Package Id                     0Ho2v000000bleCCAQ
Package Version Id             05i2v000000TNQ5AAO
Subscriber Package Version Id  04t2v************G
Tag
Branch
Created Date                   2019-12-05 18:43
Installation URL               https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t2v************G*

Comment: The asker is using 1GP, not 2GP.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm using 1GP

Comment: This actually works for 2gp. Should be the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command

```
sfdx force:package:installed:list
```

Once you've got your 1GP package Id, you can use DX to install the package to your org, eg:

```
sfdx force:package:install -p 04tf2000002Fg1SAAS
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is not exactly what I'm looking for. I want an install URL so that I can share that URL with other colleagues. They, in turn, can install that package on our customers' orgs without having to run sfdx, just by using the URL. Thanks